# A very strange case with progress events in Safari in Windows

Tags: ajax, windows, events, upload, safari

Safari gurus.
I encountered  with a very strange case with progress events in Safari in Windows.

I make a cross origin request for upload a file to S3 and all works successfully 
except the progress events in Safari in Windows.

How it normally works in Mac OS: Safari, Chrome, Firefox and in Windows Chrome, Firefox:

```
1. Start upload
2. The sequence of the progress events
3. The end - readyState == 4
```

How it strange works in Windows(Vista) Safari 5.1.7 (7534.57.2)

```
1. Start upload
2. All progress events firing in 1-2 seconds interval
3. No events until the end of the upload (60 seconds)
4. The end - readyState == 4
```

File uploaded successfully.
The problem is in events only.

The code is very simple:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = Handler;
xhr.onabort = Handler;
xhr.onerror = Handler;
xhr.ontimeout = Handler;
xhr.upload.onprogress = Handler;
xhr.open('put', S3Url, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader(...Header...);
xhr.setRequestHeader(...Header...);
xhr.send(FileObject);
```

What is wrong ?